# Minishift on OSX not accessible from local network

Tags: macos, docker, virtual-machine, openshift, minishift

I'm running minishift on OSX (tried both xhyve and virtualbox). All good, console and pods accessible from host. However cannot connect anything from local network. BTW, for regular Linux VM I configure interfaces and a bridged adapter and all is good... no idea how to do the same for minishift vm (boot2docker).

Comment: Neither ``minishift`` or ``oc cluster up`` are really intended to be exposed outside of your machine as they don't have necessary security enabled to make that a sensible thing to do. If you were to make it visible, anyone could log into the OpenShift instance and potentially then get into your machine.

Comment: Indeed, I can see that, but I just want to open them it to the local network not to the world :) Actually same thing is valid for Openshift  Origin not only Minishift. So, the bridged network works for the first call (i.e. redirects calls to local ip to cluster ip (master) so I can access login to console) but all redirects from openshift itself go to the master ip not to the bridged network adapter.

Comment: Yep, am aware of the issue. The ``oc cluster up`` command, which ``minishift`` uses internally has ``--public-hostname`` and ``--routing-suffix`` options to set what web console/REST API entry point, and host suffix for generated routes are. Using these with ``oc cluster up`` on a Mac is a pain, not sure how you might fair with ``minishift`` if they can be set. Either way, need a HTTP proxy on host to pass through requests to ``minishift`` in VM.